# Can't get all data when scrape using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm practicing to scrape my local e-commerce website using selenium and beautifulsoup. But when I try to run the code, I only get some value, and then the rest I can't get it.

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time

option = Options()

option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# block any notification
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path=os.path.abspath('chromedriver'))
driver.get('https://www.tokopedia.com/')

# click the action-figure category
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.css-15j6m2y > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)').click()

page = driver.page_source

driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'css-bk6tzz e1nlzfl3'})

for count, action in enumerate(container, 1):
    name = action.find('span', class_='css-1bjwylw').text
    price = action.find('span', class_='css-o5uqvq').text
    print('-------')
    print(count)
    print(f'nama: {name}')
    print(f'harga: {price}')
```

**I don't get any error**, but somehow the script ended without getting all the data. Is there a mistake with my approach?

P.S this is my first question in StackOverflow, am I doing it right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure class `css-bk6tzz e1nlzfl3` exists in the page source of the website you're trying to scrape? Chances are `container` is empty, can you print what's in it?

Comment: @PApostol I do. Because I search it in the inspect element. And the container is not empty you can look in this [link](https://pastebin.com/HxBbqvz1).

I already found the problem when I try to reconfirm the class name. 
Because the page not finished to load before the user scroll to the bottom. It only show first 10 item. 

thank for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the problem thank PApostol for asking the class name.

The thing is, that page won't load all the products before the user scrolls down the page. It only shows the first 10 items. After I try to scroll it down, I got all the value.

Adding this line, to scroll to the bottom of the page.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

And my code now looks like this:

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time

option = Options()

option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# block any notification
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path=os.path.abspath('chromedriver'))
driver.get('https://www.tokopedia.com/')

# click the action-figure category
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.css-15j6m2y > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)').click()

# to scroll to the bottom of the page.
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

time.sleep(10)

page = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'css-bk6tzz e1nlzfl3'})

for count, action in enumerate(container, 1):
    name = action.find('span', class_='css-1bjwylw').text
    price = action.find('span', class_='css-o5uqvq').text
    print('-------')
    print(count)
    print(f'nama: {name}')
    print(f'harga: {price}')
```

And I change the `driver.quit()` to `time.sleep(20)` because it takes time to get all products.